# How to add a reaction to bot's message

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

So I want to add an emoji reaction to the bot's message. But idk what code to make it.

I only know the code to react to the command message.

```
else if(command === "guessage"){
    message.channel.send({ embed: {
      color: 16758465,
      title: "Are you...",
      description: Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 11) + " " + "years old?"
      }
    })
    message.react('').then(() => message.react(''));

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs up.');
        } else {
            message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs down.');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.reply('you reacted with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle the promise of each `Message#reply()`

**Example Using Callbacks:**

```
message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs up.').then(botsMessage => botsMessage.react('EMOJI-HERE'));
```

**Example using Async/Await**
(Recommend for maintaining reaction order):

```
// Inside an async function
const botsMessage = await message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs up.');

await botMessage.react('EMOJI-1');
await botMessage.react('EMOJI-2');
await botMessage.react('EMOJI-3');
```

[Understanding Promises](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html) - Discord.JS

Comment: Don't use .then(). Await is clearly much cleaner. This would make spaghetti code with like 6 layers of nested promise handlers.

Comment: `.then()` is simply the synchronous way to handle a promise. My answer states "*Handle the promise of each Message#reply()*" pointing the OP in the right direction. I simply provided an **Example** not directly stating to just use `.then()` since your answer already displayed async/await. It's unfair that you downvoted my answer even though I provide *a correct solution*. Please read [Privileges - When To Downvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down#:~:text=When%20should%20I%20vote%20down,also%20need%20to%20be%20closed)

Comment: Additionally, callback hell would not be an issue when the callbacks all fit in their own one line

Comment: I now understand and would have removed the downvote, but it's locked in (maybe edit your answer just a slight bit?). Wouldn't you want to wait until the reactions are added before adding the handler in case of API delays or failure to add the reaction?

Comment: Answer has been edited to include both methods

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the sending of the message and use it's message object.

For example:

```js
else if (command === "guessage") {
    (async () => {
            let bmsg = await message.channel.send({
                embed: {
                    color: 16758465,
                    title: "Are you...",
                    description: Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 11) + " " + "years old?"
                }
            })
            await bmsg.react('');
            await bmsg.react('');

            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
            };

            bmsg.awaitReactions(filter, {
                    max: 1,
                    time: 60000,
                    errors: ['time']
                })
                .then(collected => {
                    const reaction = collected.first();

                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                        message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs up.');
                    } else {
                        message.reply('you reacted with a thumbs down.');
                    }
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                    message.reply('you reacted with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
                });
        })();
    }
```

I'm using an async IIFE to allow await to be used. There are other places where await should be used, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: I tried it and it does not work and I don't see a mistake that I made in the code. idk why

Comment: Well, we need the error and such? Running message.reply() creates a *new* message object, and your code appears to use the original. Did you make sure this function and all of it's call stack became async?

Comment: the error is 
TypeError: guessage.react is not a function

Comment: i made a function that named guessage

Comment: i'll edit my answer with a working answer